# Hibernate error:Why Generation Type.SEQUENCE is not working with postgres10.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, postgres-10

I want to use custom sequences for my postgres DB but it is always using nextval of the default sequence "hibernate_sequence" while inserting the records into the table. I am using the below code while defining the entity.

```
 @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "address_generator", sequenceName = 
    "address_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "address_generator")
     private Long id;
```

and below is the properties which I defined in application.properties file.

## The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database

```
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
       org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
       spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

## Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)

```
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
   spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I have also tried other generation strategy like GenerationType.IDENTITY,GenerationType.AUTO and the problem is same.

I am using spring boot version as 2.1.3.RELEASE.

Comment: Not all databases support autoincrement of an ID.